# Next.js with next-sitemap package not reflecting changes to /server-sitemap.xml in npm run build or production?

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, sitemap

First SO question so go easy on me.

I'm trying to dynamically generate a sitemap with next-sitemap for my next.js application. This is a rather large sitemap, with a total of about 200,000+ entries that I want to put in it.

I followed the docs for next-sitemap and got a /server-sitemap.xml page that requests the uuids of the pages I want to show and creates the sitemap. It looks like this

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { getServerSideSitemap, ISitemapField } from "next-sitemap";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const baseUrl =
    "https://redacted.com";

  const result = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/management/uuids`);
  // console.log("Result - " + result);
  const advisors = await result.text();

  //console.log(advisors);

  const fields: ISitemapField[] = advisors.split(",").map((el: any) => ({
    loc: `https://redacted.com/advisor/${el}`,
    lastMod: new Date().toISOString(),
  }));

  return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields);
};

export default function Site() {}
```

Now previously, `const result = await fetch('${baseUrl}/management/uuids');` was a different endpoint just for 8 testing uuids. And the result.test() was respectively a result.json() since that was json data.

When I was using the testing endpoint it seemed to be working properly, however when I changed it to the real endpoint I wanted to use I noticed that it was still logging the old 8 uuids.

I figured this was a caching issue and added these lines just to be sure.

```
ctx.res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "public, no-cache, no-store, maxage=0, must-revalidate"
  );
ctx.res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

and still get the old data.

Keep in mind, if I run a dev server and go to /server-sitemap.xml I get the correct response. This only fails on `npm run build`

I even tried commenting everything out and just returning empty props. But still, `npm run build` console logged the old uuids.

I've used Next.js a bit but honestly never dove too deep into how caching works and honestly I'm stumped from this issue. To make matters worse, it looks like I'm in a unique position where I haven't seen any other questions online about this issue.

I know I'm probably doing something silly and wrong somewhere in here in my code. Just not sure what.

Here is my next-sitemap config if that's any help.

```
/** @type {import('next-sitemap').IConfig} */
const config = {
  siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL || "https://redacted.com",
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  exclude: ["/profile", "/onboarding", "/server-sitemap.xml"],
  robotsTxtOptions: {
    policies: [
      { userAgent: "*", disallow: "/profile" },
      { userAgent: "*", disallow: "/onboarding" },
      { userAgent: "*", allow: "/" },
    ],
    additionalSitemaps: [
      `${
        process.env.SITE_URL || "https://redacted.com"
      }/server-sitemap.xml`,
    ],
  },
  sitemapSize: 7000,
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Are you certain the `process.env.SITE_URL` environment variable is set to the expected value when you build/run the app in production mode?